# Importing vector grid of a country from QGIS in python

Tags: pyqgis, vector-grid

I created a vector grid over a certain country (EPSG:4326) with a size of 20kmx20km (spacing) in QGIS. I want to work with this layer using Python with below goals:

1. I have pairwise locations in a file (lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2)
2. I want to map these pairwise locations onto the vector grid and get grid box indexes from the vector grid of where these pairwise locations fall.

Is this even possible using QGIS, as I am new to QGIS.

Comment: I used UK shapefile and created a vector grid of 20kmx20km in QGIS. I see the map with grids in QGIS. But is it possible to work with this data structure somehow in python. My 2 aims are listed above. I am not sure if this is even possible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible. Here is some basic code to give you an idea how this can be done using PyQGIS:

```py
grid = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Grid')[0] # load the grid layer. Replace 'Grid' with the name of your layer.

# just some example coordinates
lat1 = 50
lon1 = 14
lat2 = 70
lon2 = 2

# Making a QgsPoint out of the coordinates
point1 = QgsPointXY(lon1,lat1)
point2 = QgsPointXY(lon2,lat2)

for feat in grid.getFeatures(): # Iterate over the grid layer
    if feat.geometry().contains(point1): # Check if point 1 is within the current grid feature
        print('point1 is within feature {}'.format(feat.id()))
```

Note that you can optimize this a lot, e.g. by using a [spatial index](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.10/core/QgsSpatialIndex.html).

To provide a more final/complete answer we need you to show us your current code.

Comment: Thanks for this starting python code. I forget to mention I used QGIS desktop to do this. So my first step would be to export this layer into some format and import in into python?

Comment: @skynaive to load the layer "into python" you need the first line of this code. There are also other methods to this. Saving the grid to a file like GeoPackage, Shapefile or a DB is not necessary. You can also use a temporary layer. You just need the layer added to the QGIS Project.